# Entering text with gtk in C language

Tags: c, text, gtk

Why am I getting `Your Aggregate is(null):` in the dialogue I created.

I used `gtk_entry_get_text`, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here.

Please be quick as I have to submit my project soon.
Any good tutorials link will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by making entry1, entry2 and entry3 as global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer returned by `gtk_entry_get_text()` is temporary and not owned by you, but by the GtkEntry itself. By the time `show_info()` is called, that pointer will have been made invalid. If you alter the `GtkEntry` in any way, that pointer may also be invalid. And finally, if the GtkEntry never triggers its `activate` signal (by you pressing Enter), the global variable will still be NULL.

Fix this by not saving the return from `gtk_entry_get_text()`. Instead, call it directly from within `show_info()`. It is up to you how you will give `show_info()` the GtkEntry to pass to `gtk_entry_get_text()`.

Another way is to use `g_strdup()` in `enter_callback()` to make a copy of the entry text. You will need to manually `g_free()` the string when you are finished with it. You still have to make sure `enter_callback()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it right away.

Comment: void show_info(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer window, GtkWidget entry1) {

 GtkWidget *dialog;
 gint a = 10;
 dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),
  GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
  GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
  GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
  "Your Aggregate is %s:",entry1);
 g_signal_connect(entry1, "activate",
  G_CALLBACK(enter_callback),
  entry1);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), "Aggregate");
 gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
 gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}                                                       
Like this?

Comment: No, that opens another dialog to ask the user for the information you want to show! You already have an entry asking for the information; you just need to use it from `show_info()`, in the same way you use `window` from `show_info()`. One way to do that is to pass a pointer to a structure as the `user_data` to the button clicked signal instead; the structure will contain both `window` and `entry`.

Comment: could you tell me how I can pass it to show_info with an example, I don't understand, and I need to be quick because of my project.